# Android animation and setBackroundResource conflict?

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, gridview

I have a GridView with items that change background resource when an item is clicked. 
At the same time I want to animate a layouts position, when I do this however, the background resource for gridView item doesn't change the first time the animation is played

What i want to happen:
item is clicked 
1. item backgroundResource is changed
2.a hidden layout is shown and animated

what actually seems to be happening is:

First time when the layout is still hidden the animation is shown but the background resource of the clicked item is not changed, any subsequent item clicks set the resource as it should and the animation works.

EDIT:
I've played around a little more and the issue seems to be the visibility "gone" rather than the animation, if i set the layout to Visibility="invisible" then the resource is applied, so it seems that if the gridView is moved in any kind of way (gridView is beneath the hidden layout that i wan't to show) the resource is ignored?
i.e.:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dateDetailContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"> //instead of gone
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a Placeholder for the chosen dates' items, it's gonna look super awesome once i implement this shit"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

this is the onItemClickListener:

```
 gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

    scaleAnimateHeight(findViewById(R.id.dateDetailContainer));
    setSelectedBackground(v, gridview);
}
```

scaleAnimateHeight():

```
private void scaleAnimateHeight(View v){
    LinearLayout tv = (LinearLayout) v;
    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation expand = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.from_left);
    tv.startAnimation(expand);
}
```

setSelectedBackground():

```
private void setSelectedBackground(View v, GridView gridview ){
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_selected);
}
```

anim.from_left.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:duration="250"
      android:fromXDelta="-100%"
      android:toXDelta="0%" >
  </translate>
 </set>
```

and the layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dateDetailContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a Placeholder"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Instead of:

```
v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_selected);
```

try:

```
setImageDrawable(R.drawable.back_selected);
```

or

```
setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back_selected));
```

---

Try reversing your method calls within your listener. You are setting the resource after you change the visibility and run the animation, so it won't show until you click it the second time.

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

    //HERE
    setSelectedBackground(v, gridview);
    scaleAnimateHeight(findViewById(R.id.dateDetailContainer));
}
```

Comment: Tried that, unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the issue

Comment: does the exact same thing, animates the hidden layout but doesn't apply the background resource the first time around. Please have a look at my edit.